# MC is teleported to an exorcism in a village

Tags: story-identification, manga

All I remember is that the protagonist is assigned to purify a village together with his classmates and one of them uses a sword, in the village they talk to several villagers and discover that at night the village is full of monsters that invade it,
Later on, the protagonist discovers that the villagers are made of clay and the monsters are also created from clay and are made by an old man who stays in a hut.

Comment: I assume, based on the mention of classmates, that this might be an isekai manga?

Comment: to be more exact, he is not teleported to an isekai but it is as if it were in the current time, however with dungeons with ghosts/evil spirits

Comment: Ah, contemporary, but with monsters and villages?

Comment: yes it has villages but in parallel realities since they cross the real world with the spiritual

Comment: :) These all sound like good setting details to [edit] into your question. Also, where did you read this? Were parts of it in color, maybe the covers? Were they Japanese? All men? Mixed gender? Was it a regular high school? A military academy? An Academy of Adventure?